# Hanging clothes on a line between concrete pillars without drilling

Tags: concrete, hanging, post, temporary

Question says it all: I'd like to hang a "light" load (say 30 t-shirts/pants) between two concrete pillars, without doing anything permanent to the pillars, like drilling (they are public property and this is for a temporary event).

The pillars look something like this, except are thicker and farther apart:

[image: Concrete pillars]

I have 4mm x 30 m braided rope and would tie it around the pillars, but am worried it will slip down. This is outdoors and should carry the load in wind at 2x head height for several days, but doesn't need to be more permanent than that.

Budget solutions are also preferred, thanks!

Comment: what is above the pillars? Could you do the rope around the pillars and then something going vertically up to keep it from falling down?

Comment: Hi, the pillars are very tall and connect to a ceiling - they look approximately like this http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2034/2509023881_bfa1de47ee.jpg - will edit above to clarify

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap one end of the rope around a pillar 3-4 times, tie the loose end back to the standing portion of the rope (probably with a [bowline](http://www.animatedknots.com/bowline)), and then slide the wraps up to the top of the pillar so that the part furthest from the knot is highest, with the rope smoothly wrapping down from that point. Do the same for the other end, tightening the rope enough to get it as far off the ground as you like (use another bowline, or a [taut-line hitch](http://www.animatedknots.com/midshipmans), whichever is more convenient).

The friction between the rope and the pillar will [increase exponentially](http://sciencedemonstrations.fas.harvard.edu/presentations/rope-friction-around-pole) with the number of wraps of contact; 3-4 wraps and a relatively rough pillar will make it impossible to drag the rope down.

Answer (score 3):

Tie a [siberian hitch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siberian_hitch) at one end, then a tightenable siberian hitch, [taut-line hitch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taut-line_hitch), or [trucker's hitch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trucker%27s_hitch) at the other. This [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/Mw3lL-ofBcE) demonstrates the siberian hitch, and tightenable siberian hitch

Folks use these knots to tie lines between trees for tarps, tents, and for hanging hammocks.  If they're good enough to hang a backpacker between two trees, they should work fine for your laundry.

Comment: In light of my edit above with an image of the pillars, do you think it will still work - ie. the knot will prevent the rope from slipping down?

Comment: @JonRayner yes.  There should be enough friction to prevent the ropes from sliding down, especially if the line is pulled taut.

Answer (score 1):

1/8 aircraft cable looped around each pillar.  turnbuckle for taughtness.  super strong, easily removeable.  all in cost less than $100